# Correlated query vs inner join performance in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

let's say that you want to select all rows from one table that have a corresponding row in another one (the data in the other table is not important, only the presence of a corresponding row is important). From what I know about DB2, this kinda query is better performing when written as a correlated query with a EXISTS clause rather than a INNER JOIN. Is that the same for SQL Server? Or doesn't it make any difference whatsoever?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just ran a test query and the two statements ended up with the exact same execution plan.  Of course, for just about any performance question I would recommend running the test on your own environment; With SQL server Management Studio this is easy (or SQL Query Analyzer if your running 2000).  Just type both statements into a query window, select Query|Include Actual Query Plan.  Then run the query.  Go to the results tab and you can easily see what the plans are and which one had a higher cost.

Comment: Well, I could run it only if I had appropriately large db to test against, but I don't so I take your reply for granted :D Will do so when I do have something to test against.

Answer (score 2):

Odd: it's normally more natural for me to write these as a correlated query first, at which point I have to then go back and re-factor to use a join because in my experience the sql server optimizer is more likely to get that right.

But don't take me too seriously.  For all I have 26K rep here and one of only 2 current sql topic-specific badges, I'm actually pretty junior in terms of sql knowledge (It's all about the volume! ;) ); certainly I'm no DBA.  In practice, you will of course need to profile each method to gauge it's actual performance.  I would *expect* the optimizer to recognize what you're asking for and handle either query in the optimal way, but you never know until you check.

Comment: OK, it's also a natural way to write these for me, but this is mostly due to this DB2 deviation of mine ;). Actually this makes DB2 optimized look flawed, it should be able to recognize this as well, right?

Comment: I agree; I've usually found that the optimizer gets joins right a higher percentage of the time than correlated subqueries.  But as you say, mileage may vary.

Answer (score 1):

As everyone notes, it all boils down to the optimizer.  I'd suggest writing it in whatever way feels more natural to you, then making sure the optimizer can figure out the most effective query plan (gather statistics, create an index, whatever).  The SQL Server optimizer is pretty good overall, so long as you give it the information it needs to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Use the join. It might not make much of a difference in performance if you have small tables, but if the "outer" table is very large then it will need to do the EXISTS sub-query for each row. If your tables are indexed on the common columns then it should be far quicker to do the INNER JOIN. BTW, if you want to find all rows that are NOT in the second table, use a LEFT JOIN and test for NULL in the second table--it is much faster than using EXISTS when you have very large tables and indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best performance is with a join to a derived table.  Exists would probably be next (and might be faster). The worst performance would be with a subquery inside the select as it would tend to run row by row instead of as a set.

However, all things being equal and database performance being very dependent on the database design. I would try out all possible methods and see which are faster in your circumstances.